# PayPal redirect after payment

Tags: paypal

Hy,

I have a problem with a PayPal redirection after the payment. When the client is redirected to the confirmation page after the payment, in background I save the data into DB and I send an email with the invoice to the merchant and to the client.

For the redirection I user a **return** parameter with the value like this: http://domain.com/en/shop/shopping-cart/?wpcomethod=cosuccess&type=pp_pro&order_id=''
The order Id is a dynamic value.

But it's not working. And also I cannot put this url in the PayPal account preferences, because I have that dynamic id.

This is my form that is sent to PayPal:

```
<iframe name="hss_iframe" width="570px" height="550px" style="border:1px solid grey;box-shadow:0px 2px 8px 0.5px;position:relative;left:18%;"></iframe>
<form style="display:none" target="hss_iframe" name="form_iframe" action="https://securepayments.paypal.com/cgi-bin/acquiringweb?cmd=_hosted-payment'" method="post" id="pp-form">
<input type="hidden" value="1" name="upload">
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_hosted-payment">
<input type="hidden" name="redirect_cmd" value="_hosted-payment">
<input type="hidden" value="business email" name="business">
<input type="hidden" value="business email" name="receiver_email">
<input type="hidden" value="templateD" name="template">
<input type="hidden" value="false" name="showHostedThankyouPage">
<input type="hidden" id="lc" value="US" name="lc">
<input type="hidden" id="hLang" value="en" name="lang">
<input type="hidden" value="test" name="item_name_1">
 <input type="hidden" value="3341" name="item_number_1">
 <input type="hidden" value="1" name="quantity_1">
 <input type="hidden" value="1" name="num_cart_items">
 <input type="hidden" value="5" name="subtotal">
 <input type="hidden" value="1" name="no_note">
 <input type="hidden" value="EUR" name="currency_code">
   <input type="hidden" value="http://domain.com/en/shop/shopping-cart/?wpcomethod=billing" name="cancel_return">
    <input type="hidden" value="http://domain.com/en/shop/shopping-cart/?wpcomethod=cosuccess&amp;type=pp_pro&amp;order_id=1116" name="return">
<input type="hidden" value="CLICK HERE TO COMPLETE YOUR ORDER NOW" name="cbt">

<input type="hidden" value="2" name="rm">
<input type="hidden" value="a%3A4%3A%7Bs%3A8%3A%22order_id%22%3Bs%3A4%3A%221116%22%3Bs%3A6%3A%22buynow%22%3Bs%3A1%3A%22N%22%3Bs%3A4%3A%22user%22%3Bs%3A27%3A%22wpco52ca49f594a4d2.97750046%22%3Bs%3A7%3A%22user_id%22%3Bs%3A1%3A%224%22%3B%7D" name="custom">
<input type="hidden" value="INV1116" name="invoice">

    <input type="hidden" value="rtytester@yahoo.com" name="email">
<input type="hidden" value="1565556565" name="night_phone_a">
<input type="hidden" value="Test " name="first_name">
<input type="hidden" value="lesz" name="last_name">
<input type="hidden" value="asdsad 555" name="address1">
<input type="hidden" value="" name="address2">
<input type="hidden" value="asdasd" name="city">
        <input type="hidden" value="" name="state">
    <input type="hidden" value="454445445" name="zip">
<input type="hidden" value="FR" name="country">
<input type="hidden" value="1" name="ptype">
<input type="hidden" value="1" name="pnr">
<input type="hidden" value="5" name="ptotal">
<input type="hidden" value="0" name="pshipp">  
</form>
```

Any sugestions?

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by 'not working'. Is the buyer not redirected? Is the orderID not appended? Are all GET params lost?

Comment: By not working I mean that the user is not redirected after the payment therefore the mail with the invoice is not sent. Although I have that return parameter